# heroku-app not running after deployment

Tags: heroku

[hey, developers, I am new to Heroku and I am deploying my first app on Heroku and I am getting this error on my logs. can anyone help me out here and how do I make this thing work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xe1V.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not in the right account!
Type heroku login and put the user name and the password the heroku restart!